# vs 2015 constexpr variable non constant but fine on vs 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c++17, visual-studio-2019

I have a simple constexpr class (using c++17)

```
struct foo {
   float x, y;

   // ill formed constexpr in vs 2015
   foo() {}

   constexpr foo(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {
   }

};

constexpr auto bar() {
    return foo(4.0, 5.0);
}

int main() {
    auto f = bar();
}
```

This is illformed bc of the non constexpr default constructor on 2015. But vs 2019 doesnt report a problem.

According to [this reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) "all selected ctors" must be constexpr. I assume the word "selected" means "used" and even though default ctor is unused, 2015 wont eval into a constexpr until I make the default ctor constexpr.

Other specs are worded differently but I could not make clear of them either. Also most constexpr examples use the keyword everywhere. An example of selective constexpr use would be nice.

Latest GNU ans Clang behave like vs 2019 but Im not convinced that this was an oversight or bug in vs 2015.

So what is it? Should all ctors be constexpr or is visual studio 2019 correct here?

Comment: Can you cite which part of the spec you are quoting.  *selected* sounds like coming from overload resolution and the only viable overload is `constexpr foo(float x, float y)`.  GCC and Clang both compile as well so it sounds like you're interpreting the spec wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/e9Wmyz

Comment: Updated with a link to my reference

Comment: @Dan: "*According to the spec*" That's *not* the C++ specification; it's just a reference webpage. A Wiki at that.

Answer (score 2):

There has never been a requirement that all constructors of a literal type must be `constexpr`. The requirement has only been that all functions which get invoked in a constant expression context must be able to be constant expressions (and thus must be declared `constexpr`).

Note that older versions of Visual Studio did not do a good job of implementing `constexpr` correctly.

Comment: Yeah my tests on clang and gnu reflect 2019s behavior

Comment: The keyword constexpr was introduced in C++11 and improved in C++14.To limit the complexity of compile-time constant computations, and their potential impacts on compilation time, the C++14 standard requires the types in constant expressions to be literal types.I suggest you could refer to the [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT: I'm not really sure what you're getting at here. The type in the question qualifies as a literal type [under C++14's rules](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.types#10). Only one constructor needs to be `constexpr` for a type to qualify. That, coupled with the fact that he invokes the `constexpr` constructor, means that his code should compile in a conforming C++14 implementation.

Comment: yes thank you @NicolBolas this is why it is confusing. Possibly a vs 2015 bug?